# What happens if I XMLHttpRequest for a currently downloading file?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, prefetch

I'm trying to progressively enhance links in the [PJAX](https://www.google.com/search?q=pjax) style. I was planning on layering it on top of some regular prefetch `<link>`s:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="next.html"/>
```

If the browser has already downloaded `next.html`, the PJAX request should just hit the cache, and no harm done. But of course, since the actual fetching of prefetch links is completely up to the browser, I can't know when that will be.

I'd hate to subject users to a double download, so I've considered just taking the `<link>` off. [But browsers have started preloading/rendering on the `<link rel="next"/>` tag too](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which complicates things.

**If XMLHttpRequest hits an "in-flight" download, what kind of browser behaviors can I expect?** I'm trying to do my own research, but it's fraught with race conditions and other nastiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN FAQ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ#What_happens_if_I_click_on_a_link_while_something_is_being_prefetched.3F):

> **What happens if I click on a link while something is being prefetched?**
>   When the user clicks on a link, or initiates any kind of page load, link prefetching will stop and any prefetch hints will be discarded. If a prefetched document is partially downloaded, then the partial document will still be stored in the cache provided the server sent an "Accept-Ranges: bytes" response header. This header is typically generated by webservers when serving up static content. When the user visits a prefetched document for real, the remaining portion of the document will be fetched using a HTTP byte-range request.

Comment: This is probably the most we're going to get. Thanks!